# Как сделать кнопки по очереди?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

пытаюсь сделать ,чтобы после нажатия на кнопку и вводе текста,появлялась вторая и действия продолжадись,но кроме time.sleep ничего в голову не лезет.Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать это?

```
def family_buttons(message):

    email(message)
    time.sleep(10)

    phone_code(message)


def email(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    email = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Введите почту', callback_data='email')
    markup.add(email)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Время заполнения поля 30 секунд', reply_markup=markup)
def phone_code(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    phone_code = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Введите код телефона', callback_data='phone_code')
    markup.add(phone_code)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нажмите для заполнения поля!', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'email':
            text_email = bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Введите почту')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(text_email, next)

        elif call.data == 'phone_code':
            text_phone_code = bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Введите код телефона')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(text_phone_code, next)
```

Comment: Вы используете Aiogram?